# How to obtain the typed field instances from a typed org.jooq.Table instance

Tags: jooq

I have a function that returns an `org.jooq.Table<RecordN<.....>>` is there a way to obtain typed field instances without having to specify the types again?

```
final Table<Record11<String, Long, String, String, String, String, String, Timestamp,
                                                     String, String, Timestamp>> upcoming =
                                 tableUpcomingFor(i_app, i_req, sport_idName, minDateName);
```

At the moment I have to do something like:

```
final Field<Timestamp> minDate = upcoming.field(name("minDate"), Timestamp.class);
```

This seems redundant, I should be able to get the typed fields by position. Is there a way to do that?
I require multiple fields for use in an outer query that uses the table instance.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Can you add mode details ?

Comment: What's the definition of `tableUpcomingFor()`?

Comment: `tableUpcomingFor()` is a function that constructs a quite large query and depending on parameters looks at different columns of the base tables. But at the end of the day the result is of the form:

`return selectDistinct(...).from(...)join(...).on(....).asTable("upcoming");`